# Change activeIndex in TabView primen-g not working - angular

Tags: angular, primeng, tabview

I have a 4 tabs - TabView from PrimenG - angular. (V7)

I want that before every switch tab we check if is the tab valid.
If it's valid then we will move to the tab that clicked on
If it's not valid we want to stay on the current tab (not move).

I try a lot of options how to do that, but it's not working.
When I clicked on any tab that is invalid it will go to the tab that was clicked on, a nd that's what I don't want to happen! Because it's invalid!

This is the HTML code:

```
<p-tabView [activeIndex]="activeTabId" (onChange)="changeTab($event)">

   <p-tabPanel header="Tab 1" id="tab0" class="card" [selected]="activeTabId==0" >
        //Content
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Tab 2" id="tab1" class="card" [selected]="activeTabId==1">
        //Content
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Tab 3" id="tab2" class="card" [selected]="activeTabId==2">
        //Content
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Tab 4" id="tab3" class="card" [selected]="activeTabId==3">
        //Content
    </p-tabPanel>

</p-tabView>
```

And this is the Javascript code:

```
  activeTabId: number = 0;
  .
  .
  .
  changeTab($event) {
    let isValid = true;
    this.appService.generalData.dataList.forEach(m => {
      isValid = this.appService.generalForm.controls.dataList.valid;
      if (!isValid){
        this.activeTabId = 0 //This number (0) is just an example, We what to set the index of the current tab
      }
      else{
        this.activeTabId = 1 //This number (1) is just an example, We what to set the index of tab that was clicked on
      }
    })
  }
```

TNX for any help!

I can't think about it anymore!

And I did a lot of googling on the subject, unfortunately, without success!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `disabled` property?

For example, you can try this.

```
 <p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let tabItem of appService.generalData.dataList"  [disabled]="tabItem.valid" header="example">
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```